# How are device nodes created in Embedded Linux without udev?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, init, buildroot, busybox

I have a linux built with a buildroot for a Beaglebone wireless board. In the root file system, when it is still on the host and has not been copied to the target, in the /dev folder, there are device files fd, log, stderr, stdin, stdout only. When I load this root file system on the target and launch the target, there are many more devices - many tty, zero, urandom etc. They are created during the Linux boot process. Buildroot built the system using simple busybox init program. In init scripts i do not see the process of creating device nodes, who creates this device nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system is probably using [`devtmpfs`](https://lwn.net/Articles/330985/). It is a pseudo filesystem that is mounted on /dev where the kernel will populate device nodes for devices it knows about.
`udev` relies on `devtmpfs` since commit 220893b3cbdb ("remove mknod() logic and rely on 'devtmpfs'") which is 9 years old now.

Comment: Yes, indeed - Buildroot uses devtmpfs by default

Answer (score 0):

If your target is running busybox, you may have the `mdev` applet. Look at the installed applets with `busybox --help`.

`mdev` uses a configuration file: */etc/mdev.conf*